# How to sort by percentage on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

Now I am doing a tournament. So what I have right now is Column A is Character Names. Column B is their win Percentage. What I want is for Column C to have the Character Names in order by their Win Percentage. So basically Column A Names to be sorted in Column C by the their Win Percentage from Column B going from Highest Win % to Lowest Win %.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhuXrHx6sG1-IygMQhbbSMdlfsuykHy5C3NRCndrHLo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please read https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort()`, like this:

`=sort(A2:A, B2:B, false)`